# Set default pdf reader

Tags: debian, gnome3, imagemagick

When I install shutter to take screenshots, imagemagick sets itself as default PDF-reader and I am unable to change it.

I would like to have `evince` as default PDF-reader.

I have tried right click on a PDF document in file explorer-> Properties -> Set default application-> Evince.

This does not work, imagemagick stays as default. Doing this with the file explorer opened as root works but it doesn't change the normal-user default application.

Using xdg-mime does not help either. In `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` the default application for PDF is `evince`.

And, when I remove imagemagick-6.q16, `evince` becomes the default application for opening PDFs, but `shutter` is removed too.

Am I missing something ? Where can I change this behavior ?

I have an updated version of Debian Jessie in my computer and I am using Gnome3.

**EDIT 1:**

I can replicate this behavior with different file explorers (tested with `nemo` and `nautilus`)

The output of `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default application/x-pdf` is

```
Checking /home/USER/.local/share//applications/mimeapps.list
Checking /usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list
Checking /usr/local/share//applications/defaults.list
Checking /usr/share//applications/defaults.list
```

I've checked this files:

- In `/home/USER/.local/share//applications/mimeapps.list` I have a line with `application/pdf=evince.desktop`
- In `/usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list` the PDF reader is set to evince too.
- In `/usr/local/share/applications/defaults.list` there is no reference to PDFs.
- `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` does not exist

Comment: Which file explorer are you talking about? Linux has dozens. What does `XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default application/x-pdf` output?

Comment: I've answered your question in the EDIT 1.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't understand how Gnome applications determine what application to use to open a file. If you run `xdg-open somefile.pdf` on the command line, what application runs? What if you use `see somefile.pdf`? Does running the following command help? `grep 'pdf.*evince' /etc/mailcap >>~/.mailcap`

Comment: `xdg-open` uses imagemagick, with `see` the `file.pdf` is opened with `evince-previewer`. Creating `.mailcap` doesn't help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit the: `~/.config/mimeapps.list`, and add the line:

```
application/pdf=evince.desktop
```

to the `[Default Applications]` section. If a line for `application/pdf` already exists, change it instead of adding a new one.

Source: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591425/why-do-pdf-documents-open-with-imagemagick) on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Thanks, i had already set long ago 'application/pdf=evince.desktop;' but some lines further was 'image/pdf=...;', which  had to be set to 'evince.desktop' too.

Comment: This works for **Debian/Ubuntu** - based Pop! with **GNOME** using **Nautilus**.

Answer (score 9):

- rightclick on file
- "Properties"
- "Open with"
- select your favourite Application
- "Set as default"

[image]

Source:
https://fedoramagazine.org/how-to-select-and-set-default-applications-in-fedora/

Answer (score 7):

You can check the file `defaults.list` and change it to evince if necessary.  On my system:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list  | grep pdf
application/pdf=evince.desktop;atril.desktop
```

Comment: In a Debian system you are not supposed to change files under `/usr`. Your changes will be overwritten during package upgrades!