# set default pdf reader in debian 10 buster with cinnamon desktop

Tags: debian, cinnamon, defaults

I looked through [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226857/set-default-pdf-reader#) about setting the default pdf reader to evince. None of it seems to help for my install of debian 10.3 with the cinnamon desktop. I had a poke around and could find this:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/x-cinnamon-mimeapps.list | grep pdf
application/pdf=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-pdf=evince.deskto;
```

and this:

```
$ cat .config/mimeapps.list 

[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/tg=telegramdesktop.desktop
application/pdf=evince.desktop
application/x-ext-pdf=evince.desktop
```

and all other possible places:

```
$ grep -rnw /usr/share/applications/ -e pdf
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:16:application/pdf=libreoffice-draw.desktop;gimp.desktop;inkscape.desktop;org.gnome.Evince.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:165:application/x-ext-pdf=org.gnome.Evince.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache:359:image/pdf=display-im6.q16.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:178:Keywords=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;viewer;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:179:Keywords[ar]=pdf;ps;بوستسكربت;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;مستند;عرض;عارض;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:180:Keywords[be]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;дакумент;прэзентацыя;праглядальнік;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:181:Keywords[ca]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentació;visualitzador;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:182:Keywords[cs]=pdf;ps;postscript;postskript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokument;prezentace;prohlížeč;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:183:Keywords[da]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokument;præsentation;fremviser;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:184:Keywords[de]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;Dokument;Präsentation;Betrachter;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:185:Keywords[el]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;έγγραφο;παρουσίαση;εφαρμογή προβολής;document;presentation;viewer;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:186:Keywords[en_GB]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;viewer;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:187:Keywords[es]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;documento;presentación;visor;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:188:Keywords[fi]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;viewer;asiakirja;katselin;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:189:Keywords[fr]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;présentation;visionneur;visualiseur;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:190:Keywords[fur]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentazion;visualizadôr;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:191:Keywords[gl]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;documento;presentación;visor;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:192:Keywords[hr]=pdf;ps;postskripta;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokument;prezentacija;preglednik;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:193:Keywords[hu]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokumentum;prezentáció;nézegető;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:194:Keywords[id]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokumen;presentasi;peninjau;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:195:Keywords[is]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;skjal;kynning;skoðari;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:196:Keywords[it]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;documento;presentazione;visualizzatore;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:197:Keywords[kk]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;viewer;құжат;презентация;көрсету;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:198:Keywords[ko]=pdf;ps;postscript;포스트스크립트;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;문서;presentation;프리젠테이션;viewer;뷰어;보기;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:199:Keywords[lt]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokumentas;pateiktis;prezentacija;žiūryklė;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:200:Keywords[lv]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokuments;prezentācija;skatītājs;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:201:Keywords[nb]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokument;presentasjon;visning;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:202:Keywords[nl]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;presentatie;viewer;weergave;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:203:Keywords[pl]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokument;prezentacja;przeglądarka;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:204:Keywords[pt_BR]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;documento;apresentação;visualizador,visualização;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:205:Keywords[ro]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;viewer;prezentare;vizualizator;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:206:Keywords[ru]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;документ;презентация;просмотр;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:207:Keywords[sk]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokument;prezentácia;prehliadač;prezerač;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:208:Keywords[sl]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokument;predstavitev;pregledovalnik;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:209:Keywords[sr]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;viewer;пдф;пс;пост-скрипт;дви;икспс;дежави;тифф;документ;презентација;приказивање;dokument;prezentacija;prikazivanje;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:210:Keywords[sr@latin]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;viewer;pdf;ps;post-skript;dvi;iksps;dežavi;tiff;dokument;prezentacija;prikazivanje;dokument;prezentacija;prikazivanje;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:211:Keywords[sv]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;dokument;presentation;visare;bläddrare;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:212:Keywords[tr]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;belge;sunum;görüntüleyici;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:213:Keywords[vi]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;tài;liệu;tai;lieu;presentation;trình;diễn;trinh;dien;viewer;xem;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:214:Keywords[zh_CN]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;viewer;文档;演示;幻灯;查看器;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:215:Keywords[zh_TW]=pdf;ps;postscript;dvi;xps;djvu;tiff;document;presentation;viewer;文件;簡報;檢視器;
/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Evince.desktop:224:MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/x-xzpdf;application/x-ext-pdf;application/postscript;application/x-bzpostscript;application/x-gzpostscript;image/x-eps;image/x-bzeps;image/x-gzeps;application/x-ext-ps;application/x-ext-eps;application/illustrator;application/x-dvi;application/x-bzdvi;application/x-gzdvi;application/x-ext-dvi;image/vnd.djvu+multipage;application/x-ext-djv;application/x-ext-djvu;image/tiff;application/x-cbr;application/x-cbz;application/x-cb7;application/x-cbt;application/x-ext-cbr;application/x-ext-cbz;application/x-ext-cb7;application/x-ext-cbt;application/vnd.comicbook+zip;application/vnd.comicbook-rar;application/oxps;application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument;
/usr/share/applications/inkscape.desktop:309:MimeType=image/svg+xml;image/svg+xml-compressed;application/vnd.corel-draw;application/pdf;application/postscript;image/x-eps;application/illustrator;image/cgm;image/x-wmf;application/x-xccx;application/x-xcgm;application/x-xcdt;application/x-xsk1;application/x-xcmx;image/x-xcdr;application/visio;application/x-visio;application/vnd.visio;application/visio.drawing;application/vsd;application/x-vsd;image/x-vsd;
/usr/share/applications/display-im6.q16.desktop:14:MimeType=image/avs;image/bie;image/x-ms-bmp;image/cmyk;image/dcx;image/eps;image/fax;image/fits;image/gif;image/gray;image/jpeg;image/pjpeg;image/miff;image/mono;image/mtv;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/pcd;image/pcx;image/pdf;image/x-portable-graymap;image/pict;image/png;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/ps;image/rad;image/x-rgb;image/rgba;image/rla;image/rle;image/sgi;image/sun-raster;image/targa;image/tiff;image/uyvy;image/vid;image/viff;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-xpixmap;image/x-xwindowdump;image/x-icon;image/yuv;
/usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop:252:MimeType=image/bmp;image/g3fax;image/gif;image/x-fits;image/x-pcx;image/x-portable-anymap;image/x-portable-bitmap;image/x-portable-graymap;image/x-portable-pixmap;image/x-psd;image/x-sgi;image/x-tga;image/x-xbitmap;image/x-xwindowdump;image/x-xcf;image/x-compressed-xcf;image/x-gimp-gbr;image/x-gimp-pat;image/x-gimp-gih;image/tiff;image/jpeg;image/x-psp;application/postscript;image/png;image/x-icon;image/x-xpixmap;image/x-exr;image/x-webp;image/heif;image/heic;image/svg+xml;application/pdf;image/x-wmf;image/jp2;image/x-xcursor;
/usr/share/applications/x-cinnamon-mimeapps.list:2:application/pdf=evince.desktop;
/usr/share/applications/x-cinnamon-mimeapps.list:9:application/x-ext-pdf=evince.deskto;
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-draw.desktop:25:MimeType=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-flat-xml;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template;application/vnd.sun.xml.draw;application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template;application/vnd.visio;application/x-wpg;application/vnd.corel-draw;application/vnd.ms-publisher;image/x-freehand;application/clarisworks;application/x-pagemaker;application/pdf;application/x-stardraw;
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-draw.desktop:217:Keywords=Vector;Schema;Diagram;Layout;OpenDocument Graphics;Microsoft Publisher;Microsoft Visio;Corel Draw;cdr;odg;svg;pdf;vsd;
```

That seems to indicate that when you double click on a pdf, it should already launch with evince, but it launches with libreoffice. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you by **double click on a pdf** mean opening it from the file manager, than which manager are you using? They can have their own mime-type handling, and for example, in Nautilus you can change it by clicking on the file with the right button, opening properties, selecting **Open with** tab and setting your application as default.

Comment: Omg! I think you did it. Will reboot a bit later and make sure the change was permanent. It was however not that intuitive. Had to go into the "properties" menu upon right click then into the "open with"